# get json youtube suggestions with php

Tags: php, json, youtube

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=WORD&alt=json
```

I have this url. it creates youtube autocomplete suggestions in JSON. i must read this with php and print in html. i couldn't do that.

all the JSON decode tutorials in internet didn't work for youtube JSON.

finally, I just want a simple code to read the data and print in HTML with PHP.

Comment: Have you even thought about trying something yourself? This is very [Help Vamipre](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)-ey. Attempt a solution yourself first, then come back here with a _specific_ question.

Comment: what do you mean the json decode tutorials didn't work for youtube json? That JSON is completely valid so there is no reason for `json_decode` not to work.

Comment: yes. of course i tried very much. i am working on it for 4 days. actually i found a plugin too. i didn't give a code because no need to write json_decode. the plugin i found didn't work too. http://www.tikku.com/jquery-jqtube-util#search_example_4 this is a plugin. but i added the code and the .js files. but it didn't work too. i am not a help vampire.

Comment: @JamWaffles - That Help vampire website is an hilarious read. cheers for the link.

Comment: @Flukey Not a problem, I thought so too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$url = sprintf("http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&ds=yt&client=youtube&hjson=t&cp=1&q=%s&alt=json", urlencode("The Simpsons & family guy"));

$json = file_get_contents($url);

$results = json_decode($json);

foreach($results[1] as $result)
{
    // echo search suggestion
    echo $result[0];
}
```

There you go. After you said you've been trying to figure it out for four days, I started feeling sorry for you (I know what it is like). Enjoy the rest of your day.

**Note:** There is no validation, you should add validation but it was never asked for, so I didn't tell you ;-)

Comment: it worked like a charm. but for example the word "eylem" for, it says;

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...

Comment: @user1447165 `utf8_encode` the json before decoding it. Validation...

Comment: utf8_encode($json);

i added this before the json_decode. but still the same?

Comment: @user1447165 `json_decode(utf8_encode($json));`

Comment: thank you very much. it worked. i just wonder why my code didn't work before that line. why did it work inside json_decode? you can answer if you want...

Comment: did you just do utf8_encode($json) on one line? It's because this wasn't assigned to a variable. utf8_encode doesn't modify the `$json` variable, it simply applies a function to it and returns the output.

Comment: yes. i had used that on one line. i get it now. thanks for your help, indeed.

Comment: @hakre - "so I didn't tell you" is correct. "so I don't tell you" is wrong in this context. I'm a native English speaker :)

Comment: @Flukey: Thanks for the free lesson, I hope I will learn that one day ;)